# Pandas: How to compute a conditional rolling/accumulative maximum within a group

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I would like **to achieve the following results in the column `condrolmax` (based on column `close`)** (conditional rolling/accumulative max) without using a stupidly slow for loop.

```
Index    close    bool       condrolmax
0        1        True       1
1        3        True       3
2        2        True       3
3        5        True       5
4        3        False      5
5        3        True       3 --> rolling/accumulative maximum reset (False cond above)
6        4        True       4
7        5        False      4
8        7        False      4
9        5        True       5 --> rolling/accumulative maximum reset (False cond above)
10       7        False      5
11       8        False      5
12       6        True       6 --> rolling/accumulative maximum reset (False cond above)
13       8        True       8
14       5        False      8
15       5        True       5 --> rolling/accumulative maximum reset (False cond above)
16       7        True       7
17       15       True       15
18       16       True       16
```

The code to create this dataframe:

```
# initialise data of lists.
data = {'close':[1,3,2,5,3,3,4,5,7,5,7,8,6,8,5,5,7,15,16],
        'bool':[True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False,
                False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True],
        'condrolmax': [1,3,3,5,5,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,8,8,5,7,15,16]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am sure it is possible to vectorize that (one liner). Any suggestions ?

Thanks again !

Comment: the chosen answer is **not** doing what you requested, so there is either an error in this answer or in your question, can you please clarify?

Comment: Note that the question is to achieve the desired results in the column `condrolmax`  which is clearly shown in the question.  The term `rolling` may not precisely describe the requirement and it does not necessitate us to use `rolling()` function in the solution.  Just a matter of wording issue of the question.

Comment: There is no mention of the window size for `rolling()` (if applicable) and **the window size actually can vary depending on the pattern of column `bool`**.  Hence, if it were to use rolling function, it would at best be `expanding()` instead of `rolling()`.   In such case, it would be more straightforward to use `cummax()` within the group instead.  This is the reasoning why we choose `cummax()` instead of `rolling.max()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set group and then use [`cummax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html), as follows:

```
# Set group: New group if current row `bool` is True and last row `bool` is False
g = (df['bool'] & (~df['bool']).shift()).cumsum()   

# Get cumulative max of column `close` within the group 
df['condrolmax'] = df.groupby(g)['close'].cummax()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    close   bool  condrolmax
0       1   True           1
1       3   True           3
2       2   True           3
3       5   True           5
4       3  False           5
5       3   True           3
6       4   True           4
7       5  False           5
8       7  False           7
9       5   True           5
10      7  False           7
11      8  False           8
12      6   True           6
13      8   True           8
14      5  False           8
15      5   True           5
16      7   True           7
17     15   True          15
18     16   True          16
```

Comment: `cummax` and `rolling`+`max` it **NOT** the same thing, `cummax` would be the equivalent of `expanding`+`max`. @plonfat if this what you wanted? If yes, then please edit the question as it is incorrect

Comment: @mozway  I think OP has used an incorrect term to describe the requirement.  But what he/she wants can be seen from the expected result.

Comment: OK, thanks, I though `condrolmax` was actually the variable to work with, thanks! The question should nevertheless be edited

Comment: @mozway  I agree the wording of the question is a bit confusing.  Let's wait for a while to see whether OP will edit it.  If not, I will edit it.  No worry.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question for me and appologies for the confusion.

Comment: @plonfat  Both the question asker and answerer have their role to co-operate to get good solutions:  Question asker needs to present the question in a clear way.  Answerer needs to be carefully reading the question to understand every detail, though I agree that a clear question could also help answerer easier to understand, yet we BOTH have to do my part well.

Comment: @plonfat  No problem, I just have done minor edit to highlight the key statement that is already written clearly on the first line of the question and faint the word `rolling`.   The major explanation to make it clear is on the comment that I make it clear  **the window size actually can vary depending on the pattern of column `bool`**   Thus, not the real `rolling` that could be easily misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

First make groups using your condition (bool changing from False to True) and `cumsum`, then apply your `rolling` after a `groupby`:

```
group = (df['bool']&(~df['bool']).shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(group)['close'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).max()
```

output:

```
0     0      1.0
      1      3.0
      2      3.0
      3      5.0
      4      5.0
1     5      3.0
      6      4.0
      7      5.0
      8      7.0
2     9      5.0
      10     7.0
      11     8.0
3     12     6.0
      13     8.0
      14     8.0
4     15     5.0
      16     7.0
      17    15.0
      18    16.0
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

To insert back as a column:

```
df['condrolmax'] = df.groupby(group)['close'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).max().droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
    close   bool  condrolmax
0       1   True         1.0
1       3   True         3.0
2       2   True         3.0
3       5   True         5.0
4       3  False         5.0
5       3   True         3.0
6       4   True         4.0
7       5  False         5.0
8       7  False         7.0
9       5   True         5.0
10      7  False         7.0
11      8  False         8.0
12      6   True         6.0
13      8   True         8.0
14      5  False         8.0
15      5   True         5.0
16      7   True         7.0
17     15   True        15.0
18     16   True        16.0
```

*NB. if you want the boundary to be included in the rolling, use `min_periods=1` in `rolling`*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how we can use linear algebra and vectorizing to make this function faster, but using list comprehension, we write a faster algorithm. First, define the function as:

```
def faster_condrolmax(df):
    df['cond_index'] = [df.index[i] if df['bool'][i]==False else 0 for i in 
    df.index]
    df['cond_comp_index'] = [np.max(df.cond_index[0:i]) for i in df.index]
    df['cond_comp_index'] = df['cond_comp_index'].fillna(0).astype(int)
    df['condrolmax'] = np.zeros(len(df.close))
    df['condrolmax'] = [np.max(df.close[df.cond_comp_index[i]:i]) if 
               df.cond_comp_index[i]<i else df.close[i] for 
               i in range(len(df.close))]
    return df
```

Then, you can use:

```
!pip install line_profiler
%load_ext line_profiler
```

to add and load the line profiler and see how long each line of the code takes with this:

```
%lprun -f faster_condrolmax faster_condrolmax(df)
```

which will result as:
[Each line profiling results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d3Tm.jpg)

of just see how long the whole function takes:

```
%timeit faster_condrolmax(df)
```

which will result as:
[Total algorithm profiling result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbFrZ.jpg)

If you use the SeaBean's function, you can get better results half the speed it takes for my proposed functions. However, the speed estimated for SeaBean's doesn't seem robust, and to estimate his functions, you should run it on a larger dataset and then decide. That's all because %timeit reports like this:
[SeaBean's function profiling result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWhcl.jpg)